# use of datetime module to print time in step of given delta time

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to understand python `datetime` module. I want to increase the time by 5min between two intervals. This is what I did,

```
import datetime
start_time = datetime.datetime(100,1,1,8,0,0) # 8am
end_time = datetime.datetime(100,1,1,9,00,0) # 9am
delta_time = datetime.timedelta(0,300) # 5min intervals 


new_time = start_time + delta_time 
print(new_time.time())
```

this gives `08:05:00`. I want the result as follow,

```
08:05:00
08:10:00
08:15:00
```

How to get the rest of the time in simpler way? I am getting an error if I use a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `pandas.date_range`:

```
import pandas as pd

t_series = pd.date_range('08:05:00', '09:00:00', freq='5 min')
```

If you want only the time (just as demonstrated), use `pandas.Series.dt.time`:

```
for t in t_series.to_series().dt.time:
    print(t)
```

Output:

```
08:05:00
08:10:00
08:15:00
08:20:00
08:25:00
08:30:00
08:35:00
08:40:00
08:45:00
08:50:00
08:55:00
09:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this using `datetime`, try `while` loop as follows:

```
import datetime

start_time = datetime.datetime(100,1,1,8,0,0) # 8am
end_time = datetime.datetime(100,1,1,9,00,0) # 9am
delta_time = datetime.timedelta(0, 300) # 5min intervals

new_time = start_time
while new_time != end_time:
    new_time += delta_time
    print(new_time.time())
```

This is what you'll get:

```
08:05:00
08:10:00
08:15:00
08:20:00
08:25:00
08:30:00
08:35:00
08:40:00
08:45:00
08:50:00
08:55:00
09:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple by using the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#func-range) function and converting minutes to seconds and vice versa.
The code uses a generator expression to get a series of the datetime objects, not a list comprehension. If it needed to understand the difference between them, it is very easy to find tons of information about this on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+Generator+Expressions+vs.+List+Comprehension).

```py
from pprint import pprint # https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
f = '%m/%d/%Y:%H:%M:%S'
beg, fin = [datetime.strptime(d, f) for d in ['10/25/2015:00:00:05', '10/25/2015:23:59:58']]
step = 5 # minutes
ts = (beg + timedelta(minutes=s // 60) for s in range(0, int((fin - beg).total_seconds() + 1), step * 60))
pprint([t.strftime(f) for t in ts])
```

Output:

```
['10/25/2015:00:00:05',
 '10/25/2015:00:05:05',
 '10/25/2015:00:10:05',
...
'10/25/2015:23:45:05',
 '10/25/2015:23:50:05',
 '10/25/2015:23:55:05']
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/OSYD41728).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```
import datetime
h=8 # The starting hour
end_h=10 #the ending hour
m=0
delta=5 #delta value
while h<end_h:
    if m>55:
        h+=1
        m=0
    new_time=datetime.datetime(100,1,1,h,m,0)
    print(new_time.time())
    m=m+delta
```

Output:

```
08:00:00
08:05:00
08:10:00
08:15:00
08:20:00
08:25:00
08:30:00
08:35:00
08:40:00
08:45:00
08:50:00
08:55:00
09:00:00
09:05:00
09:10:00
09:15:00
09:20:00
09:25:00
09:30:00
09:35:00
09:40:00
09:45:00
09:50:00
09:55:00
10:00:00
```

Limitation: This technique works for a max value of end_h=24.